# How does absorbing a free thermal neutron convert nitrogen-14 into carbon-14? (Radiocarbon dating, etc.)

Tags: nuclear-physics, astrophysics, atmospheric-science, radioactivity, nucleosynthesis

Why doesn't a nuclide of N-14 simply absorb the neutron created by cosmic rays or solar wind interacting with the atmosphere and become N-15, which is stable?

How or why does the resulting Nitrogen-15 become unstable and spit out a proton, of all things?

Comment: Related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Even_and_odd_atomic_nuclei

Answer (score 0):

Neutrons from cosmic rays/solar winds are not thermal neutrons. Particles of such an origin are often as fast as from particle accelerators, even faster. AFAIK, the record of highest measured energy of a cosmic ray proton is 50 J, what is energy of flying baseball.

Formed nitrogen-15 is excited, ejecting a proton.

$$\require{mhchem}\ce{^{14}N + n(fast) ->  ^{15}N^{\ast} -> ^{14}C + p}$$